# Drop-down menu that when you click on an option a file will be downloaded

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm creating a website as a learning tool, this website has PHP code which consists of 3 drop-down menus, each of them is filled with 3 databases. And the previous one is filled dynamically depending on the previous choice.

What I want to do is when the user selects the last menu, download a file attached to that option. I don't know very well how to do this, I've been doing some research and it seems that my best asset is using javascript but I can't get it to work with my PHP code.

I think my best bet is to add another row in the database that contains the links and when the user clicks on an option it downloads according to that row.

```
<?php

//fetch_third_level_category.php

include('database_connection.php');

if(isset($_POST["selected"]))
{
 $id = join("','", $_POST["selected"]);
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM third_level_category 
 WHERE second_level_category_id IN ('".$id."')
 "; 
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $output = '';
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["third_level_category_id"].'">'.$row["third_level_category_name"].'</option>';
 }
 echo $output;
}
?>
```

- //index.php

//index.php

```
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <br /><br />
   <div style="width: 500px; margin:0 auto">
    <div class="form-group">
     <select id="first_level" name="first_level[]" multiple class="form-control">
     <?php
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
      echo '<option value="'.$row["first_level_category_id"].'">'.$row["first_level_category_name"].'</option>';
     }
     ?>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <select id="second_level" name="second_level[]" multiple class="form-control">

     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <select id="third_level" name="third_level[]" multiple class="form-control">

     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#first_level').multiselect({
  nonSelectedText:'Selecciona el driver',
  buttonWidth:'400px',
  onChange:function(option, checked){
   $('#second_level').html('');
   $('#second_level').multiselect('rebuild');
   $('#third_level').html('');
   $('#third_level').multiselect('rebuild');
   var selected = this.$select.val();
   if(selected.length > 0)
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"fetch_second_level_category.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{selected:selected},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#second_level').html(data);
      $('#second_level').multiselect('rebuild');
     }
    })
   }
  }
 });

 $('#second_level').multiselect({
  nonSelectedText: 'Selecciona el modelo',
  buttonWidth:'400px',
  onChange:function(option, checked)
  {
   $('#third_level').html('');
   $('#third_level').multiselect('rebuild');
   var selected = this.$select.val();
   if(selected.length > 0)
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"fetch_third_level_category.php",
     method:"POST",//index.php
     data:{selected:selected},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#third_level').html(data);
      $('#third_level').multiselect('rebuild');
     }
    });
   }
  }
 });

 $('#third_level').multiselect({
  nonSelectedText: 'Seleccona la serie del modelo',
  buttonWidth:'400px'
 });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways, depending on do you want download to start as soon as user selects that option or when webform is submitted.

If you want to start download as soon as option is selected then you have to go with JavaScrip. You have to add event listener to those drop-downs (probably easier would be with jQuery) and when even happens somehow trigger file download.

Other opiton is to do nothing when option is selected, but to check selected option from form submissions handler (php scrip which is called when form is submitted) and from there to start download.

Or even some hybrid options are i.e. to submit form with JS when drop value changes...

Comment: I think a button could be less confusing. Do you have any documentation so I can try to recreate one? I think since I'm already getting the third option from the table should be easier as do a WHERE $variable = X

Comment: Well, to have functional form you have to add form tag and submit button. There are a tones of examples and tutorials for this - it's most common use case. Search for it.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select